# Extract string based on the regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string variable

```
msg = "The issue is Keys on the keyboard are working intermittently . is it working? Was the Keyboard replaced earlier ?"
```

I want to extract all sentence in between "." and "?" also  "?" and "?"

Expected Output:

```
["is it working",  "Was the Keyboard replaced earlier "]
```

I am trying this pattern, but not getting the expected output

```
re.findall('(?<=\.).*(?=\?)',s)
```

**Updated String**:

> msg = " .The issue is Keys on the keyboard are working intermittently
>   . is it working? Was the Keyboard replaced earlier ?"

Comment: Why not do the obvious: `[x.split('.') for x in msg.split('?')]` with the required flattening?

Comment: re.findall(r'(?<=(\.|\?)).*?(?=\?)',s). I've not tested this.

Comment: @dyukha In this particular case Python does the right thing; switching to an `r'...'` string is certainly best practice, but doesn't change anything in this instance. Backslashes which don't have special meaning in Python strings are just passed through verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

You need Lazy-matching.
So the regex should be this.
`(?<=\.|\?).*?\?`

And the regex you have shown to me was not capturing Question mark starting sentence.

---

Test String :
`The issue is Keys on the keyboard are working intermittently . is it working? Was the Keyboard replaced earlier ?`

Regex String :
`(?<=\.|\?).*?\?`

Result :
`is it working?`
`Was the Keyboard replaced earlier ?`

Comment: No need for lazy quantifier if you add some contrast: `(?<=[.?])[^?]*\?` should do the job.

Comment: (?<=\.|\?).*?\? this pattern also captures the sentence between two "." also. Test String = "abc . bcd . dummy text ? dummy text2 ? "

Answer (score 0):

[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>] try this reglar expression to get the expected pattern.. I think you are not using a proper regular expression. this expression will find the special characters int the strings